# How to find the matrix of a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let a linear transformation in $\mathbb{R}^2$ be the reflection in the line $x_1 = 
-2x_2$. Find its matrix.

I'm aware that the reflection in y-axis is $\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1  \end{pmatrix}$. But I'm not quite sure what to do next.

Comment: Any linear transformation is determined by its action on a basis (I'm assuming that the matrix with respect to the canonical basis is what the problem is after). If you know how $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ reflect in this line, you also know how this reflection is represented by a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\theta$ be the polar angle of the line: $x_1=-2x_2$. The reflection of the vector $e_1=(1,0)$ is  the vector $e'_1$ obtained from $e_1$ by a rotation of angle $2\theta$, hence $e'_1=(\cos 2\theta, \sin 2\theta)$.

As to the image of $e_2=(0,1)$, as it is obtained from $e_1$ by a rotation of angle $\frac\pi2$, its image $e'2$ by the rerflection is obtained from the image $e'_1$ by a rotation of angle $-\frac\pi 2$, so $\;e'_2=\bigl(\cos(2\theta-\frac\pi 2),\sin(2\theta-\frac\pi 2)\bigr)=(\sin2\theta,-\cos2\theta)$.

Now, from the equation of the line, we know that $\; t=\tan\theta=-\frac 12$, so we just have to use the  formulæ
$$\cos 2\theta=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},\qquad\sin2\theta=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

A reflection matrix has the form:

$$\text{Ref}=\begin{pmatrix} \cos(2\theta) & \sin(2\theta) \\ \sin(2\theta) & -\cos(2\theta)  \end{pmatrix}$$

where $\theta$ is the angle of the line $x_1=-2x_2$ with the $x$-axis.